# How to find if an IP address falls in a range specified using a pattern? - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

If I have an IP address: 192.100.100.2 and need to ensure that it falls within a range specified using wildcard patterns.

The patterns can be either:

```
 1. 192. *. *. *
 2. *. *. *. *
 3. 192.1**. *.2
```

So essentially, an asterisk or three asterisks specify the valid range. Is there something built in in ASP.NET I can use to validate the IP address or would this be more of a custom validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AtoMerZ said, just convert your patterns to regular expressions:

```
    ''//Patterns to search for
    Dim Patterns() As String = {"192.*.*.*", "*.*.*.*", "192.1**.*.2"}

    ''//Test IP
    Dim TestIP = "192.100.100.2"

    ''//Loop through each pattern
    For Each P In Patterns
        ''//Swap two asterisk for two regex digits (\d\d) and one asterisk for one or more digits. Also escape the period
        Trace.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TestIP, P.Replace("**", "\d\d").Replace("*", "\d+").Replace(".", "\.")))
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to string and use `Regex.Match`

Comment: Not mine downvote, but probably because an asterisk (*) means different things in wildcards (match any symbol any number of times) and in regexs (match preceeding char zero or more times)

Answer (score -4):

Use this validation expression

**ValidationExpression**="\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"

example code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="321px"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Validate" />
<br />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid IP !" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></div>
```

Comment: All that's doing is checking if you have something the looks like an IP address, it's not checking if it lies within a range.